# EXCEL - incorporating ROUND to IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, rounding

I'm trying to calculate accurate capscrew lengths between to connections where one side is drill & tap and the other is a flange. For some reason I can't post the image; essentially I've got a bunch of dimensions from B4 through B10 with a yes or no on B8 followed by dimension thrown in on E8

Current formula for optimal length looks like

```
=IF(B4>0,(((B4-B5)/2)+B5)+B7+IF(E8>0,E8)+IF(B8="yes",B7)+B9," ")
```

I need the number to round to the nearest +1/16

I thought I could do

```
=IF(B4>0,(ROUND(((B4-B5)/2)+B5)+B7+IF(E8>0,E8)+IF(B8="yes",B7)+B9),.0625)," ")
```

but i get an error saying that I've entered too few arguments for the function and after clicking ok it highlights the B5.

Any suggestions?

Comment: First, you should check the parentheses. They are strange (before ROUND???).

Comment: If I don't have the parentheses before round, I don't understand how it could differentiate the if statement from the round statement? but removing the parentheses didn't work either

tried:=IF(B4>0,ROUND(((B4-B5)/2)+B5)+B7+IF(E8>0,E8)+IF(B8="yes",B7)+B9,.0625," ")

Comment: It might be easier to explain the logic behind this, rather than have folks diagnose a formula that doesn't work with no context.

Comment: Sorry Kyle, I'll edit my original post

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your formula is doing, but I'm guessing instead of ROUND() you want FLOOR() or CEILING()... Eg =FLOOR(A1,1/16) or CEILING(A1,1/16)

Comment: Round needs 2 arguments. 1) The number you want to round, 2) how many digits you want it rounded to. You haven't put that 2nd argument in (or at least Excel doesn't think you have, based on your parentheses).

Comment: Isn't the argument for what I want it rounded to indicated after the B9? It's still not working if I add an extra () around my calculation then around again around the Round argument =IF(B4>0,(ROUND(calc),.0625)," ")

I tried: 
=IF(B4>0,(ROUND((((B4-B5)/2)+B5)+B7+IF(E8>0,E8)+IF(B8="yes",B7)+B9),.0625)," ")

Comment: This is paranthetical hell right here. You have formulas getting chopped in half by other formula's parantheses. And to top it off your second parameter for `ROUND()` is `.625`. That argument is the "Number of digits" `.625` is nonsense. Perhaps something like: `=IF(B4>0,ROUND((((B4-B5)/2)+B5)+B7+IF(E8>0,E8)+IF(B8="yes",B7)+B9,3)," ")` or something... There's a lot of wrong happening here.

Comment: Either way the the formula JNevill suggested doesn't work either. 

I need it to round to the nearest 1/16" which is why i selected .0625 as my rounding number.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. In that case you'll need to use `=MROUND()` to get to the nearest multiple. `=IF(B4>0,MROUND((((B4-B5)/2)+B5)+B7+IF(E8>0,E8)+IF(B8="yes",B7)+B9,.0625)," ")`  When I get stuck deep in the parentheses, sometimes I'll stick the formula in Notepad++ which is nice about highlighting matching pairs. It will help suss out what is what a little easier than excel's editor.

Comment: Thanks JNevill, That seemed to work!!

Comment: Always helps to have the correct number of ().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MANY THANKS to JNevill

=IF(B4>0,MROUND((((B4-B5)/2)+B5)+B7+IF(E8>0,E8)+IF(B8="yes",B7)+B9,.0625)," ")

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/MROUND-function-86dc90eb-1e0e-4e03-8913-6debe3f18c5f

However, this only rounded to the nearest (which is what I asked for) and not always up .

I believe =CEILING() is more of what I was needing for because it is rounding to the next highest 1/16.

=IF(B4>0,CEILING((((B4-B5)/2)+B5)+B7+IF(E8>0,E8)+IF(B8="yes",B7)+B9,0.0625)," ")

https://support.office.com/en-za/article/CEILING-function-f3b5f222-592b-4557-ae9a-05707d756509

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to figure out your exact application, here is how to round a number to the nearest 1/16th:

```
=ROUND(OptimalLength*16,0)/16
```

Where OptimalLength is the calculation your are completing before the rounding either on another cell or inline.

Hope this helps. Cheers,